# How to handle active state of multiple dropdown menus in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component `Dropdowns` which renders a group of dropdown menus.

When multiple menus are rendered, clicking on a dropdown opens all of them at the same time. How can I make sure I only toggle the active state of one dropdown?

`Options` prop determines how many `Dropdowns` get rendered. `id` is simply for development so I can find it in devtools easier, in the case I have multiple `Dropdowns` on one page.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import * as style from './Dropdown.module.css';

const Dropdown = (props) => {
  const { options, id } = props;
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(0);

  const handleActive = () => {
    setActive(!active);
  };

  const setSelectedThenCloseDropdown = (index, filter, item) => {
    filter.handler(item);
    setSelectedOption(index);
    setActive(!active);
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (index, filter, item) => (e) => {
    switch (e.key) {
      case `Escape`:
        setActive(false);
        break;
      case ' ':
      case 'SpaceBar':
      case 'Enter':
        e.preventDefault();
        setSelectedThenCloseDropdown(index, filter, item);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={style.dropdownWrapper} id={id}>
        {options.map((option) => {
          return (
            <div key={option.current.id + option.current.name} className={style.dropdownWrapper}>
              <div className={style.dropdownContainer}>
                <button
                  role="button"
                  onClick={handleActive}
                  aria-haspopup="listbox"
                  aria-expanded={active}
                  type="button"
                  className={style.dropdownToggle}>
                  {option.current.name}
                </button>
                {active && (
                  <div
                    role="listbox"
                    aria-activedescendant={option[selectedOption]}
                    tabIndex={-1}
                    className={style.dropdownMenu}>
                    {option.list.map((item, index) => {
                      /* istanbul ignore next */
                      return (
                        <a
                          role="option"
                          tabIndex={0}
                          onKeyDown={handleKeyDown(index, option, item)}
                          aria-selected={selectedOption == index}
                          className={style.dropdownItem}
                          key={item.name + option.current.name}
                          onClick={() => {
                            option.handler(item);
                            setActive(false);
                            setSelectedOption(index);
                          }}>
                          {item.name}
                        </a>
                      );
                    })}
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Dropdown;
```

Comment: You only have one "active"/"setActive" and one "selectedOption"/"setSelectedOption" shared between multiple dropdowns.  I think each dropdown should be a separate component which has its own state variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your 'active' hook an object to store the status and the ID of the dropdown that is active.

```
const [active, setActive] = useState({id: null, status: false});
```